# Word with multiple meanings

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

"The **invisibility** of women's **concerns** in society"

Q1. What does "invisibility" mean here? "Ignorance conducted by men?" or something else?

Q2. What does "concerns" mean? Is it "worries" or "interest" or "importance"?

Q3. Would you rephrase the above phrase for me to understand plainly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Invisibility** means "lack of recognition." This could mean that politicians do not think about women's concerns when writing laws, and journalists do not think about them when conducting interviews and writing articles, and people "on the street" do not think about them when conducting their day-to-day activities.

**Concerns** means "things that affect their lives." *Women's concerns* could be quite a range of things, for example:

- I am not allowed to own my own property or make my own financial decisions.
- I am not allowed to decide for myself whether or not to have children.
- I do not like wearing these types or styles of clothes, but I am expected to wear them.
- I want to do a specific job or work in a particular industry, but I will not be hired because I am a woman.
- Medical researchers only study men, so if my symptoms for a disease do not match men's symptoms I will not get proper medical care.
- I am expected to act a certain way; if I act as men do my social status will be reduced.

**To rephrase**, perhaps: "The lack of attention paid to issues women care about..."

Comment: Your explanation is so clear and elaborate. Thank you:)